# Spring MVC + GWT : Redirect Issue

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, gwt, redirect, annotations

I am using Spring annotated MVC framework in an app which I am developing.

Following is the issue I am facing:

1. I have Controller which does a redirect, after a POST:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/emdm-viewer-redirect.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView getMetricKeysAndRedirect(@RequestParam Object jsonObject, Model model) 
   {
           ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/mdm-viewer.do");
           .....
           .....
           ....//make some service calls and populate value1
           ...
           modelAndView.addobject("param1", value1);
           return modelAndView;
   }
   ```
2. I have another controller which is mapped to URL mdm-viewer.do (The redirect URL mentioned above):

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/mdm-viewer.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getMDMViewer(Model model) {
           return "mdmViewer";     //returns a mdmViewer.jsp
   }
   ```

Please note that the mdmviewer.jsp is a GWT entrypoint which is in classpath.
I have my firebug window open which tells me that a GET request was made for mdm-viewer.do, but it gives me a blank response. In fact, it does not redirect to the new jsp and stays on the same page from where the POST request was made.
However, if I copy the firebug URL and open it in a new window of my browser, I see the expected results.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Tried to google it a lot, but can't find a similar issue anywhere.

Comment: Does firebug shows you a 302 response code in the first request ?

Comment: Nope. Firebug displays that the request was successful. But, the response tab in Firebug is all blank. And its showing the same result in all my browsers (Chrome, IE and Firefox).

Comment: It means that you have not been redirected. Can you try this ? : "redirect:mdm-viewer.do without the "/"

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I returned a ModelAndView back from the POST method using a
        @ResponseBody 
And in my GWT Module, I used the response.getText() output to do a

```
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONParser.parse(response.getText());
            String viewName = jsonObject.get("viewName").isString().stringValue();
            JSONObject jsonParams = jsonObject.get("model").isObject();
            Set<String> chartKeys = jsonParams.keySet();
            String redirectURL = viewName + "?";
            for (String keyString : chartKeys) {
                    redirectURL = redirectURL + keyString + "=" + jsonParams.get(keyString).isString().stringValue() + "&";
                }
            Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + redirectURL, "_self", "");
            }
    }
```